Can Zn dust remove an alcoholic groups from any alcohols?
I know that zinc dust is used to obtain benzene from phenol. But can zinc get oxidised and remove OH group from a simple alcohol, for example ethanol?

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87840/reaction-of-phenol-and-zinc-dust https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81717/effect-of-zn-dust-reduction-of-phenolic-oh-group-on-other-groups

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60959/are-groups-other-than-carbonyl-reduced-by-clemmensen-reduction

No, not in any synthetically useful way
It has been observed here that the reaction of zinc powder with aliphatic alcohols at $\pu{330^\circ C}$ under solvothermal conditions produces $\ce{ZnO}$ nanoparticles. The reaction involves the cleavage of the $\ce{C-O}$ bond on the metal surface. The focus of this work appears to be the production of $\ce{ZnO}$ nanoparticles rather than the reduction of the alcohols.
$\ce{Zn}$ plus $\ce{NH4Cl}$ can reduce aldehydes and ketones to alcohols as described here but no alkanes are produced.
Standard Clemmensen ($\ce{Zn/HCl}$ or $\ce{Zn(Hg)/HCl}$) conditions reduce carbonyl compounds to alkanes passing through the intermediate alcohol, but the HCl is a key component here for protonation of the alcohol.

How can zinc powder react with alcohol to produce $\ce{ZnO}$ without reducing the alcohol ?

I can only see the abstract of the paper and no comment is made about the fate of the aliphatic groups - whether simple reduction occurs or a more complex process of oligermerisation

Give me the reference of this article. I am pretty sure I can read the entire article, and not simply the abstract.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10876-007-0129-6#:    Journal of Cluster Science vol 18 (2007) 660-670

Thank you for the reference in the Journal of Cluster Science. Reading it gives the equations for the reaction between zinc powder and alcohols. At $330$°C, the reaction is : $\ce{2 ROH + Zn -> R2 + ZnO + H2O}$. So methanol produces $\ce{R2}$ which is ethane, and ethanol produces $\ce{R2}$ which is n-butane
